# Cabal cannot install dates and semigroup

Tags: haskell, cabal

If I execute `$ cabal install semigroup`, I get the error

```
Data/Semigroup.hs:29:22: error:
Ambiguous occurrence ‘Semigroup’
It could refer to either ‘Prelude.Semigroup’,
                         imported from ‘Prelude’ at Data/Semigroup.hs:2:8-21
                         (and originally defined in ‘GHC.Base’)
                      or ‘Data.Semigroup.Semigroup’,
                         defined at Data/Semigroup.hs:22:1
   |
29 | instance Monoid a => Semigroup (Identity a) where
   |                      ^^^^^^^^^
```

(repeating itself at several other occurences)

Similarly if I `$ cabal install dates`,

```
Data/Dates/Types.hs:62:10: error:
• No instance for (Semigroup DateTime)
    arising from the superclasses of an instance declaration
• In the instance declaration for ‘Monoid DateTime’
   |
62 | instance Monoid DateTime where
   |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
cabal: Leaving directory '/tmp/cabal-tmp-16926/dates-0.2.2.1'
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
dates-0.2.2.1-ILbYRzHuQkwCfqySpiVks0 failed during the building phase. The
exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

Is this a bug? and how to work around it?

Comment: To have a better experience for handling dependencies, try stack instead of cabal if you can https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README/

Comment: Stack helps some people with some things but it isn't a silver bullet to all things.  In this particular case it seems understanding the general ecosystem is helpful.  N.B. `stack install semigroup` ~> `Unknown package: semigroup`.

Comment: The dependency bounds on the problematic version of `dates` seem to have been fixed: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/dates-0.2.2.1/revisions/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Semigroup class is now part of base in GHC 8.4.x:

```
class Semigroup a where
  (<>) :: a -> a -> a
  GHC.Base.sconcat :: GHC.Base.NonEmpty a -> a
  GHC.Base.stimes :: Integral b => b -> a -> a
  {-# MINIMAL (<>) #-}
        -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
```

But in older versions of GHC it was not part of base and originally lived in the `semigroups` package.  Older still than `semigroups` is `semigroup` which you are trying to install and similarly conflicts with what is now part of `base` (thanks @Li-yao for the comment).  So semigroup, the package, should not be used with the newer ghc/base.

Your second problem is that version of `dates` is not updated for the new base, which requires all Monoid instances to also be an instance of Semigroup:

```
class Semigroup a => Monoid a where
  mempty :: a
  mappend :: a -> a -> a
  mconcat :: [a] -> a
  {-# MINIMAL mempty #-}
        -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
```

You could file an issue with the `dates` package.

Comment: `semigroups` is the previous canonical source for that class. `Semigroup` has not been updated since 2011.